# Docker compose mongo wont create root user

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to create to compose a docker container with a mongo image. I want the container to have a root user called `admin` and also be able to create a database called `experts_db`. Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:4.0.4
        container_name: mongodbtest
        restart: always
        env_file: .env
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456789
            MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: experts_db
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        volumes:
             - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```

and here is my `mongo-init.js` file:

```
use admin;

db.createUser(
        {
            user: "andrea",
            pwd: "123456789",
            roles: [
                "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                   "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
                   "readWriteAnyDatabase"

            ]
        }
);
```

Despite that, when I am in the mongo shell and try to get a list of all users, I get the following error:

```
use experts_db
switched to db experts_db
> db.getUsers()
2020-01-22T14:30:00.569+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: command usersInfo requires authentication :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.getUsers@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1763:1
@(shell):1:1
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I am new to mongo and dont understand how I could fix this

Comment: what's the `use admin;` line in the js file? doesn't look like javascript

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the data/db/ volume inside your container then rerun and build again

```
rm -rf data/db/.  # This command should be run from within the container
docker-compose up --build
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the JS script below and it works as expected:

```
db.createUser(
{
    user: "aaa",
    pwd: "123",
    roles: [ { role: "readAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }]
});
```

After the creation, you can hop on mongoDB shell and run db.getUsers() to make sure the user has been successfully created.

Comment: Do you know if your docker instance is executing the JS file properly? Can you try to  test it locally (outside of container) first to make sure the JS file works?

Comment: Good to know it works outside of containers. Please try to mount the volume like this: ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js (without the :ro at the end).